# How to do unit testing with complex business logic with lots of different code paths?

Tags: unit-testing

This is an example of a typical function from a project I used to work on. I have troubling grasping unit testing because if I want to test this function properly, I would have to write about 50-100 unit tests to cover most of the possible code paths to ensure all the logic works correctly, and this is just a very small part of the application.

Almost every function with business logic is like this, and 90% of the codepaths for each function are critical, which means that if the codepath has a bug then the entire function is broken. While it's reasonable to refactor this function, the algorithm must be the same after refactoring, and that means you can't avoid writing the same amount of tests after refactoring, the only thing refactoring would change is that some of the test would be integration tests rather than unit tests. How do real world projects thoroughly test everything with automated without spending so much time writing tests to the point you would take more time writing tests than manually testing everything? Is there anything I'm missing?

```
    private async Task ValidateItem(Item item, IEnumerable<Item2> items2,
        ValidatorCache cache, CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        (bool prop1IsValid, var propData) = await cache.ValidateProperty(item.Property1, cancellation);
        if (propData != null)
        {
            item.Property1 = propData.NAME;
        }
        Item2 Item2 = null;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Item2Id))
        {
            Item2 = items2.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == item.Item2Id && a.Code == item.Code);
        }
        PropData correctPropData = null, item2PropData = null;
        if (Item2 == null)
        {
            item.ItemState = ItemState.DoesNotExistInItems2;
            if (prop1IsValid)
            {
                FillFields(propData);
                correctPropData = propData;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            bool prop2Valid = false;
            item.Property2 = Item2.NAME?.ToUpperInvariant();
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property3))
            {
                item.Property3 = Item2.Property3;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property4))
            {
                item.Property4 = Item2.Property4;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property5))
            {
                item.Property5 = Item2.Property5;
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property6))
            {
                item.Property6 = Item2.Property6;
            }
            (prop2Valid, item2PropData) = await cache.ValidateProperty(item2.Property2, cancellation);
            if (prop1IsValid && prop2Valid)
            {
                item.ItemState = ItemState.OK;
                item.ChooseProp = ChooseProp.Prop1;
                correctPropData = propData;
            }
            else
            {
                if (prop1IsValid)
                {
                    item.ItemState = ItemState.OK;
                    item.ChooseProp = ChooseProp.Prop1;
                    correctPropData = propData;
                }
                else if (prop2Valid)
                {
                    item.ItemState = ItemState.OK;
                    item.ChooseProp = ChooseProp.Prop2;
                    correctPropData = item2PropData;
                    item.Property1 = item.Property2;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.ItemState = ItemState.Property1Error;
                    return;
                }
            }
            FillFields(correctPropData);
        }
        if (Item2 == null && item.ItemState != ItemState.Property1Error && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property7) && item.Flag != true)
        {
            string prop = item.Item == ChooseProp.Prop2 ? item.Property2 : item.Property1;
            var validator = new Prop7Validator(await cache.GetProp7(prop, cancellation));
            item.Property7 = validator.GenerateProp7(item);
        }
        else
        {
            if (item.ItemState != ItemState.Property1Error && correctPropData != null)
            {
                string prop7 = item2 != null ? item2.Property7 : item.Property7;
                var validator = new Prop7Validator(await cache.GetProp7(correctPropData.NAME, cancellation));
                item.Property7 = validator.GetMissingData(prop7, item);
            }
        }
        if (correctPropData != null)
        {
            var prop7Data = await cache.GetProp7(correctPropData.NAME, cancellation);
            var validator = new Prop7Validator(prop7Data);
            if (!validator.ValidateProp7(item.Property7))
            {
                item.ItemState = ItemState.Property7Error;
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property3))
            {
                item.ItemState = ItemState.MissingProperty3;
            }
            else if (item.Property8 != "2" && item.Property9 <= 0)
            {
                item.ItemState = ItemState.InvalidProperty9;
            }
            else
            {
                item.ItemState = ItemState.OK;
            }
        }

        void FillFields(PropData propData)
        {
            if (item.Property3 == "01" && item.Property9 > 0)
            {
                item.Property10 = item.Property9;
            }
            item.Property11 = propData.m012;
            if (item.Property11 == "2")
            {
                if (item.Property3 == "2" && item.Property9 > 0)
                {
                    item.Property12 = item.Property9;
                    item.Property10 = item.Property9;
                }
                else if (item.Property10 > 0)
                {
                    item.Property12 = item.Property10;
                }
                else
                {
                    item.Property10 = item.Property12;
                }
            }
            else if (item.Property3 == item.Property11)
            {
                item.Property12 = item.Property9;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that a function of that complexity actually has a single responsibility. (I'm _hoping_ that you've just obfuscated the variable names for this example, but if not that's an even bigger problem).

Comment: Since "90% of the codepaths for each function are critical" and you don't have tests, you don't actually have much confidence that this works. So you might as well delete it, and start over by implementing small, focused functions - a function, or an object, for each rule, like your "validateProperty", and write tests for those. Then maybe write some functions/objects for simple combination of rules, test those. Maybe you pass a callback to be executed if the check passes. 1/2

Comment: Then use those within ValidateItem, by combining them into some sort of a mostly linear chain. You should have very few or no if-s. You might want some other function to accept this chain or validation rules, and produce and return ValidateItem (as a lambda, or an object); test if the right chain of functions is passed, and if they are actually called. 2/2

Comment: I do have confidence that this function works, since it's been tested manually and put into production. Deleting this and starting over is insane. It should be refactored, but I want to know if there is a way to automate part of writing tests so I don't have to write hundreds of tests for each function or class.

Comment: Philip, it depends on what you think is a single responsability. This function validates an item of some kind (it's obfuscated of course) and part of that validation includes loading data from some other table into the item. To the people who define the requirements, it's a single piece of functionality, but that piece of functionality includes multiple steps. It doesn't matter if it does a single thing or not, all I want to know is how people manage testing algorithms with lots of codepaths.

Comment: Well, it's no more insane than refactoring without tests. But, I didn't necessarily mean literally - refactoring is just deleting the old code slowly; what I'm saying is that you shouldn't leave this as is, it will come back to bite you (and is already biting you). Also, you completely missed my point about how changing the design can make testing more manageable. You say you want to know how people manage testing code with lots of codepaths - divide and conquer, and re-express your code, until you find a better design that removes and/or merges some codepaths, & removes test redundancies.

Comment: There is SO MUCH opportunity in this code to do better. Quite some duplication, or code that could be easily extracted into helper functions. For example, there's this code for filling in defaults from Item2, the code for choosing prop1 or prop2 (in which the "prop1 AND prop2" branch is redundant), the code for determining an ItemState if correctPropData  is available. When faced with lots of steps, people typically test that each step is correct in all circumstances, and that the steps work together – but not that all paths through the entire code base are covered.

Comment: Philipp, it quite obviously has the single responsibility to validate the item.

Comment: @gnasher729, indeed. And my 1,000,000 line app has but a single responsibility: fulfil a set of user requirements. So I've put it all in one function...

Comment: If all the codepaths are critical .. you have to test all the codepaths. That's just how it is. You can reduce the workload somewhat by not trying to test each path entirely independently, but it does a lot of stuff so it needs a lot of tests.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with what [VoiceOfUnreason said](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/433642/3965) about refactoring to better support unit testing. For an extreme example, if you have 10 composed functions, each with 2 paths, it takes 20 unit tests to test them individually, but there are over 1000 path combinations if you glom them all together in one function.

That being said, I don't think 50 tests for 139 lines of relatively dense code is particularly excessive, especially if you're writing them TDD-style and get into a rhythm. There is usually one way for a function to go right,  but several error cases to handle.

Comment: It is a little difficult to imagine that simply moving code to other objects reduces the number of code paths that need testing. It might become easier to see what tests need to be written, but an if-elseif-else is still 3 paths, no matter which class the logic belongs to.

Comment: I agree with Greg here, and that is the reason that I ask this question. Refactoring only splits one function into many, but the total number of codepaths is still the same if you actually refactor properly and don't end up changing the algorithm.

Comment: @Magnus Refactoring is not splitting a function, refactoring is maintaining the same abstract behavior (which is what the test should test), while messing with the internal structure (including splitting, merging, re-expressing the code in terms of new concepts, introducing or removing elements, etc.).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: refactoring doesn't mean you completely rewrite the internals. It could simply mean you split the code into multiple functions - essentially giving a name to a group of statements without actually changing the number of code paths.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - sure, but I didn't say that it's "completely rewriting the internals"; I've said spiting is just a small subset of a wider range of refactorings that you could do (since Magnus said that it "only splits one function into many" - and doing only that kind of refactoring is not going to help much here).

Comment: @GregBurghardt: Let's say I flip a coin, roll a die, and pick one letter, all in one go. That's 2×6×26=312 possible outcomes. But if I have a separate coin flipper, that has 2 possible outcomes. A dice roller has 6 outcomes. A letter picker has 26 outcomes. So you now only write 2 coin picking tests, 6 dice rolling tests, and 26 letter picking tests, for a total of 34 tests. That's an almost 90% reduction in how many outcomes you need to test.

Comment: @Flater if you have an arbitrary function of the coin flip, die roll, and letter pick, that still has a state space of 312 inputs.

Comment: @Caleth: And the need for 100% coverage of the state space dissolves due to rigorous unit testing of individual components; a handful of integration tests can confirm the integration of the components. If you demand 100% coverage, sure, then you have to cover 100%. But then you inherently choose to work hard, not smart; rendering the basis of the question moot.

Answer (score 6):

> How to do unit testing with complex business logic with lots of different code paths?

Refactor the complex business logic so that it better supports unit testing.

"Design is what we do to get more of what we want than we would get by just doing it." -- Ruth Malan.  In this case, what we want is easier testing of the complex logic, so we replace the design that puts all of the complexity into a single hard to test lump (unit), and instead distribute that logic over a number of smaller lumps that are each easier to test.

In other words, we make "the complicated bits need to be easy to test" a design constraint, and any design that doesn't satisfy this constraint is either rejected or forced to evolve into a design that does.

See also [Integrated Tests are a Scam](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VDfX44fZoMc) (J. B. Rainsberger, 2015).

Comment: How does refactoring reduce the total number of codepaths to be tested? This algorithm defines exactly how the functionality must work, if this function is split into many smaller functions and the functionality is identical then the total number of codepaths to be tested must be the same. Instead of writing 50 tests for one function you write 10 tests for each function. But you must write 50 tests to test everything. I want to know if there is a way to save time.

Comment: Short answer: we're trying to detect mistakes.  We're not trying to count how many code paths reach each mistake.

Comment: To detect mistakes it is needed to test most codepaths, otherwise you won't catch a lot of errors.

Comment: @Magnus: Separation avoids exponential growth. Let's say I flip a coin, roll a die, and pick one letter, all in one go. That's 2×6×26=312 possible outcomes. But if I have a separate coin flipper, that has 2 possible outcomes. A dice roller has 6 outcomes. A letter picker has 26 outcomes. So you now only write 2 coin picking tests, 6 dice rolling tests, and 26 letter picking tests, for a total of 34 tests. That's an almost 90% reduction in how many outcomes you need to test.

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason: _Refactor the complex business logic so that it better supports unit testing._

Let's say I have complex business logic inside a single method that uses a lot of other objects. I separate the BL in several private methods that are called from one public method. From my tests suite I'd test only the public method, and I'd still have the problem to build complex test scenario to meet all the preconditions that all the referenced objects need to execute properly. How would you proceed in this case?

Comment: Most common approach: have the private method delegate its work to some other module, and then apply your mistake detection strategy to that other module (ex: A::privateMethod delegates its work to B::publicMethod; now apply your mistake detection strategy to B).

Comment: @VoiceOfUnreason: Thanks, I'll keep in mind this approach.
By the way, sometimes it could seem kind of a forcing to create new objects just to put in them some public methods, while they should belong to the initial object.

Answer (score 4):

Proper separation of logic leads to avoiding the exponential growth that leads to "lots of different code paths".

I suspect that you have not (or incorrectly) separated your logic, either mentally or in code, which is causing you to only consider tests that involve many variables; as opposed to individually testing each component of the (overall) complex business operation.

Keep in mind that you're talking about **unit testing**, but the tests you describe are of a complexity that is more related to integration tests, where more than one components is being tested at the same time.

Had this code been posted to CodeReview.SE, I would've strongly urged you to refactor this code. However, as your question is about testing, I'll limit my answer to the assumption that your business logic is fixed and we're only focused on the test strategy for this given business logic.

*For what it's worth, when we're focusing on the amount of tests you need to write, it makes no difference whether your code is refactored into multiple classes, or if you write specific tests for specific parts of your existing code.*

---

> I would have to write about 50-100 unit tests to cover most of the possible code paths

*Even if* you did not refactor your code any further, which you IMHO should, it still wouldn't take this many tests to confirm that this code works as expected. By properly separating your concerns, which in this case refers to what your tests specifically assert, you can dramatically reduce the amount of test cases needed.

> the only thing refactoring would change is that some of the test would be integration tests rather than unit tests

Au contraire. What a refactor would do is give you the ability to write **simpler** unit tests because you'd be dealing with **simpler** components. You shouldn't just integration test your complex business logic and leave it at that. Integration tests should only be an addition to a test suite that is already backed by unit tests for all individual components. Integration tests without unit tests give no indication as to which component failed where and why.

You're dealing with a bunch of `if` blocks, and you can (and should) write tests that only assert specific parts of the logic, not an entire output value. For the sake of example, I'll whittle your code down to 3 `if` blocks:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property3))
{
    item.Property3 = Item2.Property3;
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property4))
{
    item.Property4 = Item2.Property4;
}
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Property5))
{
    item.Property5 = Item2.Property5;
}
```

If you write tests that test a *complete* data set, you'd have to write 8 tests, because you need to combine three different binary states (property is/isnot null or whitespace). The test cases would be:

- All are null or whitespace
- 3 and 4 are null or whitespace, 5 is filled in
- 3 and 5 are null or whitespace, 4 is filled in
- 3 is null or whitespace, 4 and 5 are filled in
- 3 is filled in, 4 and 5 are null or whitespace
- 3 and 5 are filled in, 4 is null or whitespace
- 3 and 4 are filled in, 5 is null or whitespace
- All are filled in

This is every permutation possible for three properties that can either be filled in or whitespace. The math here is:

```
 (options for 3) x (options for 4) x (options for 5)
 = 2 x 2 x 2
 = 2³
 = 8
```

But this is not how you should write your tests. Instead, you should tests for these three properties **separately**. This reduces your total tests to 6 tests:

- 3 is null or whitespace
- 3 is filled in
- 4 is null or whitespace
- 4 is filled in
- 5 is null or whitespace
- 5 is filled in

The tests for 3 will not test nor assert anything about properties 4 and 5. They are only interested in property 3. The values of 4 and 5 do not meaningfully impact the behavior of property 3, and therefore it makes no sense to write additional test cases whose different values make no impact to the test's focus.

The math here is:

```
 (options for 3) + (options for 4) + (options for 5)
 = 2 + 2 + 2
 = 6
```

Mathematically, you've turned your multiplication into addition. The amount of tests that this saves you increases (pound for pound) as the amount of testable logical paths increases.

As we just established, for 3 binary states, this is a reduction from 8 to 6, which is 25% less.
But if we have 10 of these binary states to test, this is a reduction from 1024 (2<sup>10</sup>) down to 20 (2+2+2+...), which is an **98% reduction**.

Not all of your `if` blocks are binary. Sometimes you have more complicated evaluations which have more than two possible input permutations. But the principle remains the same.

Even when we're not discussing testing strategies but code maintenance instead, this is precisely why proper abstraction and separation of concerns is so powerful. By separating your logic, you can have a complex whole that is made up of individually simple components, which makes each component easy to maintain and test; while at the same time allowing your application to perform much more complex tasks that by themselves would not be as maintainable.

Comment: "The tests for 3 will not test nor assert anything about properties 4 and 5. They are only interested in property 3. The values of 4 and 5 do not meaningfully impact the behavior of property 3, and therefore it makes no sense to write additional test cases whose different values make no impact to the test's focus." In this example that is not true for the tests relating to filling props2 to 6 if Item2 is not null, determining which of Prop1 and Prop2 are correct, validating Prop7 and calling FillFields with the Prop1 or Prop2, determining ItemState. All those have dependencies with each other

Comment: Refactoring does not magically eliminate data dependencies or ifs that are related. If I test properties separately then I can't detect inconsistencies between different properties that are related which are 99% of bugs that end up being detected. Your advice can't help about half of the ifs statements in this example because they have data dependencies with each other.

Comment: Testing individual components can't catch errors introduced when these individual components are assembled together. You can mock dependencies but that is no substitute for actually testing all of the code with real data so you know that everything works.

Comment: @Magnus: [In response to first comment] Many people have already told you that your code is too complex. I changed the example code to something more parseable for the sake of clarity of my explanation. I agree with you that your code is much more complex and not as easily split into separate tests. However, that doesn't invalidate my answer, it just adds further incentive to actually refactor your code.

Comment: @Magnus: [In response to second comment] Sufficient refactoring _does_ elimininate contrived dependencies. You're either thinking about a level of refactoring that doesn't get you the whole way, or you're going about the refactoring the wrong way. Your code has clear sections that are contextually different. In the first comment you even pointed out one of those ("filling props2 to 6 if Item2 is not null"). These kinds of sections are ripe for abstraction, which in turn simplifies the overall testing. Again, your feedback just add more incentive to refactor, rather than invalidating the answer

Comment: @Magnus: [In response to third comment] I specifically addressed that you can still integration test on top of your unit tests, because I agree that unit tests alone tend not to cover your entire test case need. **However**, your code is poorly abstracted and logically contrived. In such cases, you run into many potential side effects, thus warranting a lot of testing and vetting, but _again_, this is a problem of your own making by not properly abstracting your logic into constituent components. [..]

Comment: [..] With proper abstraction, a lot of these potential side effects cease to exist, which in turn simplifies your needed testing strategy. To sum up your three comments and most of your responses on this page; you are correct that there are _further_ problems in your code; but you are not acknowledging that the source of these further issues stems from how your code has been structured - as opposed to somehow proving that the given comments and answers don't apply to your case or help you.

Comment: @Magnus: Maybe a better analogy: if you ask a truck salesman if the truck can transport a piano and still drive well, he will say yes. If you ask him the same about any instrument, he will  always say yes. But if you put an entire orchestra in the truck at the same time, and the truck cannot drive well; this does not prove that the salesman lied to you. Your code is the logical equivalent of a truck loaded with an entire orchestra's instruments. It is overloaded, bulky and unwieldy; which makes for a horrible driving (testing/coding) experience. The solution is to not overload the truck.

Comment: I don't see how refactoring can eliminate dependencies without breaking functionality. Most of the ifs depend on each other: Prop7 MUST be validated with the correct Prop1 or Prop2, Prop3 to Prop6 MUST be filled with the data from Item2, FillFields MUST be called with the correct Prop1 and Prop2 which must be the same that validates Prop7, and the final ItemState set depends on all the prior steps. If you remove ANY of these dependencies then the code is broken, because it doesn't have the exact same functionality.

Comment: Refactoring the code does not magically detect bugs that happen when each step works fine individually but then a bug is introduced when they are combined.

Comment: @Magnus: _"Refactoring the code does not magically detect bugs that happen"_ Indirectly, it does, by enhancing testability, which in turn improves the bang for your buck (effort vs reward) you get from time spent writing tests. _"bugs that happen when each step works fine individually but then a bug is introduced when they are combined"_ That's what _integration_ tests are for, not unit tests. By definition, unit tests do not test the interaction between several real components. Integration tests do. But integration tests should be backed by unit tests for each used component.

Comment: then how do you write integration tests such that all codepaths are tested?

Comment: @Magnus: Your line of questioning is going in circles because you are ignoring what several people have been telling you. You've responded that you don't understand how refactoring can help you,  but that doesn mean that it can't. It just means you need to investigate this further as opposed to dismissing it.

Comment: I have investigated further but I don't think I will get it unless I see a real world case just like the ones in my previous job get refactored and tested with 100% coverage. I hope I can experence that in my new job...

Comment: @Flater sorry if i missed the point, but I am curious about how you would go about writing an integration test for the example you gave. Wouldn't you still end up having to write the 8 tests that test all permutations anyway (if you really wanted to test that the function was working as expected)?

Comment: @Ryn If you've already written individual unit tests for every individual scenario; then there's no further need to integration test every possible combination of scenarios - that's just confirming the same thing again. The ability to create lean integration tests (because they are already backed by rigorous unit tests) depends on how much possible interaction there is that cannot possibly be tested in individual cases. Fizzbuzz is somewhat of an example here. You can't just test the 3 case and the 5 case, since the 15 case is an exceptional interaction between the 3 and 5 cases. [..]

Comment: @Ryn [..] Don't take the fizzbuzz example too literally - it would require the 3 case and 5 case to be separate unit testable components. The point here remains that you should ask yourself if there is sufficient interaction between the individual components. If yes, then that interaction needs to be integration tests. If no, then your unit tests cover your cases, and you can get away with a much simpler integration test suite (maybe even just a happy path integration tests that just confirms there's no compatibility issues between the components).

Comment: @Ryn Let me put it differently, in response to _"if you really wanted to test that the function was working as expected"_: I'm going to play a game where I flip the same coin 5 times. For testing purposes, I want to confirm that the game will not be rigged. Do I need to test _the coin_, or _how the coin behaves when flipped five times_? I think you're arguing the latter case. However, I can reasonably argue that the coin flips are all repeatable actions, and if I confirm that it's a fair coin for one flip, I've proven it for any amount of flips. Disconnecting the chain makes it easier to test.

Comment: @flater thanks for the reply, i think that does make a lot of sense. If we test every individual scenario, then basically every ancestor function would also need to test every individual scenario of its descendant functions - this is simply not feasible. Actually i made another post on unit testing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76692593/mocking-child-functions-in-unit-testing, and I believe your answer has answered my 1st question in the post. However, I wanted to get your thoughts on the 2nd question and how we can go about mocking child functions to write more isolated unit tests.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is complicated. It could be made a bit less complicated, but it’s mostly complicated because your business logic is.

There are two dozen places where you could hide a trivial bug. So yes, you need to have at least two dozen unit tests. Best to give a printed description of the business logic to someone who then writes the unit tests (you shouldn’t write unit tests base on your code). And then you want to make sure that your unit tests would find bugs. Spend 10 minutes: introduce a bug on the first line of code, run unit tests, something should fail, introduce a bug on the second line and so on. If a bug doesn’t fail, tell the unit test writer what went wrong and let them add a test.

Comment: Basically it sounds like you are advocating for black box unit testing. Not a bad approach here. Authors make assumptions about their code that complete strangers do not.

Comment: I wouldn't even call it black box testing. There's just too much risk that someone starts writing the unit tests by extracting bits from the implementation, and duplicates any bugs. So if the code contains "item.Property9" in some place instead of "item.Property8" there is too much of a risk that the unit test copies that bug. This code is just _asking_ for trivial and stupid bugs.

Comment: This example was among the least complicated in my project. There are examples that are 100 times more complicated

Comment: @Magnus Congratulations. I feel for you. There's the saying "better you than me". Oh well, I have some complicated code for parsing data from an API where the data is just what volunteers entered. Where "Date of Birth" might be "2nd century BC", for example.

Comment: @gnasher729 fortunately I've just started a new job, but I want to know how to test extremely complex code without just writing basic tests and calling it a day. Particularly at a business where everything is critical yet can't afford to spend 3x more time writing tests.